# Malformed keywords on extraction PHP

Tags: php, text-extraction, malformed

I am extracting keywords from webpage using this [resource](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/php_tip_how_extract_keywords_web_page). It works fine but some words are getting malformed. The word "**memory**" is extracted as "**memori**" and "**article**" is extracted as "**articl**". There are many other keywords with similar behaviour. [Here](http://pastebin.com/stRLr2my) is a list(var_dump($uniqueKeywords)) of some keywords extracted from [this](http://nadeausoftware.com) URL as an argument to the function.

P.S.: I am not stripping off the numbers.

Comment: what function you are exactly using? what is your requirement?

Comment: The page I've linked as resource has all the functions. And I've used them exactly. I've also applied the Stemming algorithm. I've only not used the Strip Numbers function. I've put all these functions in a function and gave it the URL given in the question as an argument.
Requirement is unique keywords from a single page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words are transformed using a [Stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) algorithm.  Stemming allows different forms of a word to match, e.g. **"memory"** and **"memories"** both transform to **"memori"**. Note that the stemmed words usually aren't actual words, but should only be use for comparison.

If you don't want this behaviour, skip the ['Stem the words'](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/php_tip_how_extract_keywords_web_page#Stemthewords) section of the tutorial.

Comment: Alternatively, accept this behaviour. If you want to use the keywords as means to find similar content, this is actually good for you since you can link "memory" to "memories", which would otherwise be two different words.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I've to calculate the frequency of these unique keywords in later functions. The word "memory" comes 7 times on the URL I've linked. I need to eradicate this behaviour somehow. Is there some other Stemming library which can extract it correctly or they will all act the same ?

Comment: @Arnold: I am not much familiar with text processing techniques. Is there any other technique that will not behave like this ?

Comment: @SilentAssassin This is not a technique. You are doing this in your code by calling `$words[$key] = PorterStemmer::Stem( $word, true );`. So if you don't want that comment out that part of the code.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels I know that very well. I want the word "memory" only. I want minimum number of keywords and I want to eradicate this behaviour.

Comment: @SilentAssassin I've already answered you're question. Either use stemming while extracting and also on your search/compare terms or don't use stemming at all. Don't use stemming on only 1 of them. If you're looking for an algorithm that converts 'memories' to 'memory', it can't be done.